# caratheodory extension theorem - extension of sigma-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis

I have been (very painfully) trying to self-teach myself measure extensions from textbooks & stuff on the internet. I am very confused about a number of things with regards caratheodory extension theorem (since there seems to be multiple different versions of it given). A couple of questions:

1. in some texts, the outer measure is defined on a measure on ring (eg wiki entry, Halmos, http://www.probability.net/WEBcaratheodory.pdf#measure), whilst in others (eg [https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/3-05-out-meas.pdf](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/real-an/3-05-out-meas.pdf),  [http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kisilv/courses/math3263m014.html](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/%7Ekisilv/courses/math3263m014.html), it is defined on a measure on a semi-ring. Why the difference?
2. Most of the derivations of caratheodory based on rings & semirings seem similar eg [http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgav/teaching/notes/notes.pdf](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgav/teaching/notes/notes.pdf). However I have come across these 2 proofs which treat sigma-finite measures differently:

[https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~potapov/5825_2013/notes/sigma-finite-extension.pdf](https://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/%7Epotapov/5825_2013/notes/sigma-finite-extension.pdf)
[https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sawyer/handouts/MeasuresSemiRings.pdf](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Esawyer/handouts/MeasuresSemiRings.pdf)

Is the proof given in the first link still applicable when we are extending a sigma finite measure or does it need to be treated differently as per the final 2 links? Moreover is the proof given in the first link applicable to the semi ring of half closed intervals on the real line (where the underlying set is the real line)?

Many tks!
Ian